# How to deploy a solana program from a particular address or public key

Tags: node.js, rust, blockchain, solana

I've two problems here, major of all, I can't understand the difference between ***account address*** and ***public key of a program***

The second thing is, there is a problem while deploying my solana program. I've made a deployment script...

```
const { Keypair } = require("@solana/web3.js");
const { Connection, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } =  require("@solana/web3.js");
const path = require('path');
const spawn = require("cross-spawn");
const fs = require('fs');

//import { Connection, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } from "@solana/web3.js"

async function main(){
    const SLASH = path.sep;

    let programAuthorityKeypair = new Keypair();
    this.connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com", "confirmed");

    const signature = await this.connection.requestAirdrop(programAuthorityKeypair.publicKey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * 5);

    await this.connection.confirmTransaction(signature);

    const programAuthorityKeyfileName = `target/deploy/programauthority-keypair.json`
    const programAuthorityKeypairFile = path.resolve(
        `${__dirname}${SLASH}${programAuthorityKeyfileName}`
    );

    fs.writeFileSync(
        programAuthorityKeypairFile,
        `[${Buffer.from(programAuthorityKeypair.secretKey.toString())}]`
    );

    const programKeyfileName = `target/deploy/solblog-keypair.json`
    const programKeypairFile = path.resolve(
        `${__dirname}${SLASH}${programKeyfileName}`
    );

    let programKeypair = readKeyfile(programKeypairFile);

    let programId = programKeypair.publicKey.toString();

    //////////////////////////////////configurations//////////////////////////////////

    let method = ["deploy"] // we are deploying for the first time, using 'deploy'

    spawn.sync(
        "anchor",
        [
            ...method, // we use a variable so we when we want to upgrade, we can use 'upgrade' instead
            "--provider.cluster", // we want to specify the node cluster
            "Devnet", // the node cluster as the Devnet
            "--provider.wallet", // we need to pass in a keyfile to pay for the deployment
            `${programAuthorityKeypairFile}`, // this is the keypair file we created just a moment ago
        ],
        { stdio: "inherit" }
    )

}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
});

function readKeyfile(keypairfile) {
    let kf = fs.readFileSync(keypairfile)
    let parsed = JSON.parse(kf.toString()) // [1,1,2,2,3,4]
    kf = new Uint8Array(parsed)
    const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(kf)
    return keypair
}
```

now, I'm running the script by `node deploy.js` but it is giving me balance insufficient error...

```
Deploying workspace: https://api.devnet.solana.com
Upgrade authority: /home/adil/Desktop/solblog/target/deploy/programauthority-keypair.json
Deploying program "solblog"...
Program path: /home/adil/Desktop/solblog/target/deploy/solblog.so...
===========================================================================
Recover the intermediate account's ephemeral keypair file with
`solana-keygen recover` and the following 12-word seed phrase:
===========================================================================
all orbit slim nothing learn country polar casual print help coffee gesture
===========================================================================
To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the
[BUFFER_SIGNER] to `solana program deploy` or `solana write-buffer'.
Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the
[BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to `solana program close`.
===========================================================================
Error: Account JjetRg5FHM6xpPjTT7KfrEaTBeEWxMh5Pyjo4UXw3nm has insufficient funds for spend (1.8711612 SOL) + fee (0.00135 SOL)
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

so I'm taking the above account address `JjetRg5FHM6xpPjTT7KfrEaTBeEWxMh5Pyjo4UXw3nm` to solana faucet site, and airdropping 5 SOLs into that address then again I'm running the script, AND GETTING THE SAME ERROR WITH DIFFERENT ACCOUNT like...

Error: Account .

already set the env to the DEVNET.

What I'm thinking that how can I deploy the program with the same account into which I'm airdropping SOLs?

Comment: Did you tried `solana config url --set devnet && solana airdrop 2` to get airdropped & `solana balance` to check ?

Comment: Again, the same error.

Comment: if thats the case then i recommend making a new program and re deploy with sufficient funds